# how do i turn this into an iife with event listeners i tried below but it doesn't function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to turn this into a iife so that it doesn't use the global variable which is interfering with other code, but I'm not sure how any help would be very appreciated thank you. I also want to be able to use event listeners instead of inline handlers but not sure how to do it all

```
(function () {var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}}());




  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> 
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>  
  </div> <!-- slideshow-container -->
</div>  
<div class="dot-container-for-slide-banner">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
</div>
```

this was the original script

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`

None of the Html provided has the `.mySlides` class, so your `var slides` contains no elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements like you do it now, and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach handlers like `currentSlide` and `plusSlides`, instead of using attributes. So, for example it would be something like this for dots:

```js
var dots = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dot"));
// with for loop
for (dot of dots) {
  dot.addEventListener("click", function () {
    currentSlide(dots.indexOf(dot) + 1);
  });
}

// or with `.forEach`
dots.forEach(function (dot, index) {
  dot.addEventListener("click", function () {
    currentSlide(index + 1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an IIFE, the functions declared within the IIFE would not be available outside of the IIFE, as a result, the HTML elements do not have access to the functions `plusSlides`, `currentSlide` and `showSlides`, which is actually what you wanted to do (not polluting the global scope)

In order the attach the event handlers, you can use the `.addEventListener` method on the elements, in stead of writing them inline.

```js
(function () {
  var slideIndex = 1;

  init();

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides((slideIndex += n));
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides((slideIndex = n));
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
  }

  function init() {
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');

    // add the click event listeners to the dots elements
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      // we need to use an iife here also to prevent the unexpected
      // value of i, or we can use the `let` keyword if that's available
      (function (index) {
        dots[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
          currentSlide(index + 1);
        });
      })(i);
    }

    // add the click event listeners to the arrow elements
    document
      .querySelector('.prev')
      .addEventListener('click', function () {
        plusSlides(-1);
      });
    document
      .querySelector('.next')
      .addEventListener('click', function () {
        plusSlides(1);
      });

    showSlides(slideIndex);
  }
})();
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> -->
<a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next">&#10095;</a>

<div>
  <div class="mySlides">slideshow 1</div>
  <div class="mySlides">slideshow 2</div>
  <div class="mySlides">slideshow 3</div>
  <div class="mySlides">slideshow 4</div>
</div>

<div class="dot-container-for-slide-banner">
  <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> -->
  <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> -->
  <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> -->
  <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> -->
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Also, for this to work, your script should be placed at the end of the `body` tag